# What will be connection string to Access database file with PHP

Tags: php, ms-access, connection-string

I installed WAMP, I have access database file in project folder, but don't have installed Access on my computer.

Can I read and update Access file with PHP even I don't have installed Access?

And what will be connection string to Access database file?

I really need help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is the [PHP api for ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php).
Here is the example from the docs itself:

```
<?php
// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver - allows connection to SQL 7, 2000, 2005 and 2008
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

// Microsoft Access
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);

// Microsoft Excel
$excelFile = realpath('C:/ExcelData.xls');
$excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

// Microsoft Access

1. Open the Administrative Tools icon in your Control Panel.
2. Double-click on the Data Sources (ODBC) icon inside.
3. Choose the System DSN tab.
4. Click on Add in the System DSN tab.
5. Select the Microsoft Access Driver.
6. Click Finish.
7. In the next screen, click Select to locate the database.
8. Give the database a Data Source Name (DSN).
9. Click OK.

   ```
   $dsn='database.accdb';
   $username='';
   $password='';
   $connect=odbc_connect($dsn, $username, $password);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'v found [this](http://www.configure-all.com/php_access.php) link with a tutorial on how to do it. Be careful that things work differently in windows and UNIX environment, but since you are using a WAMP you should have no problems

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$db = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/AccessDatabase/reg.accdb"; //AccessDatabase is folder in htdocs where the database is store 
if (!file_exists($db))
{
       die("No database file.");
}

$dbNew = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$db; Uid=; Pwd=;");
$sql = "select * from reg"; //reg is table name
$rs = $dbNew->query($sql);

while($result = $rs->fetch())
{
     echo $result[0].": ".$result[1].": ".$result[2]."<br />";
} 


?>
```

If u got error like pdo ODBC Drivers not installed 
just go to php.ini and find extension = pdo_ODBC Driver and remove the comment(;)
after that restart the apache

Comment: Please explain a bit more using proper English so as to make your answer more useful to readers, thanks